# didSelectRowAtIndexPath working on simulator not iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Hopefully a nice and quick one for you...
the below code is working fine on the simulator, but not working on the iPhone, any ideas?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if([[dataTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Telephone"]){
        NSString *tel = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:(@"tel://%@"),[selectedData objectForKey:@"telephone"]] autorelease]; 
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:tel]];
    } else {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com"]];
    }   
}
```

**Edit

To expand a little by not working I mean, when the (in this case) second tableview cell is clicked Safari pops up with www.apple.com on the Simulator. Nothing happens with the other command as no phone on simulator. But on iphone nothing happens on either cell click.

Comment: Hi tob, I have expanded the main post a little

Comment: Did you debug? Is the `openURL`-line called?

Comment: For some reason I have a problem on my iphone 4 that wont let me see any output but when I had a NSLog placed before both openURL calls on the simulator they both came up.

Comment: What if you use the Debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out, after a bit of playing the 'Base SDK' was set to iOS Simulator 4.0 not iPhone 4.0.